# Edit GDM login screen (not background)

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, login, gdm

I have fingerprint authentication enabled and password disabled. Still the login screen shows the rectangle where you write the password. I doesn't affect my login since it is disabled but I wish to remove it to make it visually better.

I tried commenting password related "objects" in the gnome-shell.css file but did not work. Any ideas?

I have Gnome 3.38.2 on Archlinux.

Comment: By editing `gnome-shell.css` file you can achieve that. But it will be a hack only. I think the reason it exists bcoz any other user can use "not listed"??

Comment: Right! Useful point. Will try around that